# How can FastCGI service access the wfastcgi.py file from python(root)/site-packages/wfastcgi/wfastcgi.py location

Tags: python, iis, cgi, fastcgi

I was able to configure the FastCGI service so that whenever the client requests any call it will create only one process and serve all the requests.

This service is working only If the wfastcgi.py file present in python root directory.

If I install that python module (wfastcgi) using pip install wfastcgi, it will go to python(root)/site-packages/wfastcgi/wfastcgi.py file.

If I specify the above path (python(root)/site-packages/wfastcgi/wfastcgi.py) in web.config file, it is not taking it. default IIS/FastCGI error is throwing by saying that...

```
500 Internal Server error: <handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration
```

We wanted to place this file in the installed directory itself meaning under site-packages.

My question here is how can we specify the site-packages location to the FastCGI service (There are no folder permission errors).

Comment: The error message says it all. Only registered FastCGI applications can run.

Comment: Lex, Can you elaborate on this? What kind of configuration we need to do so that the wfastcgi.py file under site-packages can access it.

Comment: The error message itself refers to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/ if you do a Google search. Read the documentation and register the actual application file path, then the error message would disappear.

Comment: Yes, I made those changes in applicationHost.config file under <fastcgi> TAG. it is working now. Thank you Lex